# Sum of two positive numbers is a negative

Tags: x86-16, emu8086

So I'm creating a simple 8086 program that calculates the sum of two two digit numbers:

```
.model small
.data

    first db 0
    second db 0
    sum db 0

.stack

.code

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    sub al, 48d
    mov bl, 10
    mul bl
    mov first, al

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    sub al, 48d
    add first, al

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    sub al, 48d
    mov bl, 10
    mul bl

    mov second, al

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    sub al, 48d
    add second, al

    mov al, first
    add al, second
    mov sum, al
```

However when I check the value of the numbers specifically the sum it gives me a negative number as it's signed value. For example if the first number is 99 and the second one is 98 the sum is -59.

Does anyone have an answers that might fix this problem?

Comment: the first bit of number is its sign.
So if the addition goes one bit further, it will become a negative number.
If you don't understand, learn about representation of numbers in the system, as well as some calculations in Binary.

Comment: it feels like an integer overflow problem 99+98=197, 197 in unisgned binary is `11000101` which is -59 if we read it as signed integer. With only 8 bit representation the highest positive number is 127

Answer (score 0):

Since you used a byte for each number, every number can have 2^8 = 256 different values. So signed numbers must be between -128 and 127. When addition result get larger than 127, it represent it as corresponding negative number. You should use word(16-bit) or more to solve this problem.